# Get age from date_of_birth with age greater than 35

Tags: mysql, sql

```
# Customer table contains 3 columns - id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth

create table Customer(id integer, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), date_of_birth datetime);
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(1, 'Akash', 'Agarwal', '1985-09-03');
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(2, 'Harish', 'Gupta', '1981-09-24');
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(3, 'Ramesh', 'Reddy', '1992-01-03');
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(4, 'Bhola', 'Banerjee', '1975-05-03');
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(5, 'Gagan', 'Mani', '1968-05-02');
insert into Customer(id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth) values(6, 'Mahesh', 'Iyer', '1988-05-09');
```

This mysql query is not working

```
select timestampdiff(YEAR, date_of_birth, curdate()) as age
from Customer
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1970-02-01', CURDATE()) > 35;
```

the output should look be only age greater than 35

Comment: Your entire `where` clause contains no column references, so will be the same for all rows.

Comment: And your entire `select` clause is one expression that computes `age`. How were you expecting `name` to show up?

Comment: If you know could you please help me

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you bro it worked

Answer (score 1):

select timestampdiff(YEAR, date_of_birth, curdate()) as age from Customer where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) > 35;

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps neater way using `having`:

```
select timestampdiff(YEAR, date_of_birth, curdate()) as age
from Customer
having age > 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer:

```
where date_of_birth < curdate() - interval 35 year
```

However, that doesn't use the age that you have specifically calculated.